# read excel file and add into java entity class

Tags: java, excel

I am reading excel file using jxl library.But I am facing a problem when i want add the cell content into pojo class  property . such I have Employee class;

```
public class Employee {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }




}



public static void read(String path) throws IOException {
        File inputWorkbook = new File(path);
        Workbook w;
        String[] excel_data  = new String[3]; 
        try {
            w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
            // Get the first sheet
            Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
            // Loop over first 10 column and lines

            Vector<Employee> data = new Vector<Employee>();
            for (int j = 1; j < sheet.getRows(); j++) 
              { 

                          Employee emp = new Employee()
               for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getColumns(); i++) 
               { 
                   Cell cell = sheet.getCell(i, j);
                 //  d.add(cell.getContents());
                               emp.setId(cell.getContents());
                              emp.setName(cell.getContents());
                              emp.setEmail(cell.getContents());
                }
                 //  d.add("\n");
                   data.add(emp);   

                //insertEmployee(emp);
            }
```

here my code i can add cell content into vector object. but i want set cell content value into Employee class property.Please tell how I achieve this.I am not getting right value from emp object.What I was doing   wrong  in  my code when i adding content into list

Comment: Maybe you can post an error message, so that we know what is wrong.

Comment: What does the call to cell.getContents() return? What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: i do not want add into vector but i want to add into generic List<Employee> object

Comment: i am updating code where I want to add

Comment: Do you know which cells int the spreadsheet that corresponds to which values for the Employee? What is the problem you have encountered, specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set the values manually.

You can write a switch statement and set the values for each column index like this:

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
...
Employee emp = new Employee();
for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getColumns(); i++) 
{ 
    Cell cell = sheet.getCell(i, j);
    switch (i) {
    // column 0 = ID
    case 0:
        emp.setId(cell.getContents());
        break;
    // column 1 = Name
    case 1:
        emp.setName(cell.getContents());
        break;
    // column 2 = Email
    case 2:
        //... etc
        break;
    }

}
employees.add(emp);
```